# Referencing/Embedding Documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, mongomapper

one simple schema:

```
Company embeds (many) Departments
Company/Department references (many) Employees
```

First i tried this with Mongoid (my preferred ODM) with no success. Known MixedRelation issue of Mongoid.

Then i tried the follwoing simple association with MongoMapper:

```
c = Company.first
d = Department.first
e = Employee.first

c.departments << d
c.save
```

so far so good, but...

```
c.employees << e
or
d.employees << e
or
c.departments.first.employees
```

throws: NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!

whats wrong ?

Comment: Ok guys, i did it. I simply forgot to cast the employee_ids of type Array

Comment: @David, could you post your solution as an answer to your own question and accept it? It will help others who are searching for the same thing find the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for that late Answer.

All you have to do is to create key to store all the ids in and than create a reference to that key. Here is a small example.

```
class Department
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument
  ...
  key :contact_ids, Array
  ...
  many :contacts, :in => :contact_ids
end
```